# finding the position function of a body moving in a medium with velocity $v(t) = -0.2t^2 + 0.7t + 0.5$

Tags: calculus

Based on an experiment lasting $2.5 \text{ minutes}$, the velocity of a body travelling in a medium may be modeled by the equation $$v(t) = -0.2t^2 + 0.7t + 0.5 \frac{\text{metres}}{\text{minute}}$$
Where t is the number of minutes from the start position

i) Find the position function $D(t)$ that the body has moved from the start position

ii) Find the total distance traveled in the first $\text{minute}$

iii) Find the total distance traveled in the first $2 \text{ minutes}$

My answer for i):

$$ v = -0.2t^2 + 0.7t +0.5 \frac{\text{metres}}{\text{minute}}$$ Where $t = 2.5 \text{ minutes}$.
$$ s = \int_0^2.5 - 0.2t + 0.7t +0.5$$
$$= \frac{-0.2t^3}{3} + \frac{0.7t^2}{2} + 0.5 (t) + c$$

I have got this far. I now need to $2.5$ in to the above and this gives the distance over $2.5 \text{ minutes}$. But this is where i am struggling. Can someone help me complete this? So i can then try to solve , ii), iii)

Comment: There is a trivial relationship: $s(0)=0$. You can determine $c$ by using this and thereby $s(1)$ and $s(2)$.

Comment: While you have correctly found the integral function of $v(t)$ in the first question, there are some typos on the first line of the solution. Remember to write $dt$ at the end, and also that **the result that of a definite integral is a real number**, not a function in this case. So remember to plug in the limit values.

Comment: I will remember to write dt at the end. i just was unsure how to place and calculate to 2.5 in to this.

Comment: You should not use $2.5$ but rather a variable $T$ as your upper integration limit, isnce you want to calculate the distance function (i.e. distance at time T) rather than total distance.

Answer (score 1):

The position of the body at time $T$ is given by
$$s(T) = \int_0^T v(t)~dt = \int_0^T (-0.2t^2 + 0.7t + 0.5)~dt$$
Integrating with respect to $t$ yields
\begin{align*}
s(T) & = \left(-\frac{0.2t^3}{3} + \frac{0.7t^2}{2} + 0.5t\right)\bigg|_0^{T}\\
     & = \left(-\frac{0.2T^3}{3} + \frac{0.7T^2}{2} + 0.5T + 0 - 0 - 0\right)\\
     & = -\frac{0.2T^3}{3} + \frac{0.7T^2}{2} + 0.5T
\end{align*}
In calculating the total distance traveled, we must find 
$$d(T) = \int_0^T |v(t)|~dt$$
Observe that 
\begin{align*}
v(t) & = -0.2t^2 + 0.7t + 0.5\\
     & = -\frac{1}{5}t^2 + \frac{7}{10}t + \frac{1}{2}\\
     & = -\frac{1}{5}\left(t^2 - \frac{7}{2}t\right) + \frac{1}{2}\\
     & = -\frac{1}{5}\left[t^2 - \frac{7}{2}t + \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot -\frac{7}{2}\right)^2\right] + \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot -\frac{7}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\\
     & = -\frac{1}{5}\left(t^2 - \frac{7}{2}t + \frac{49}{16}\right) + \frac{49}{80} + \frac{1}{2}\\
     & = -\frac{1}{5}\left(t - \frac{7}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{89}{80}
\end{align*}
Observe that 
\begin{align*}
v(t) & \geq 0\\
-\frac{1}{5}\left(t - \frac{7}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{89}{80} & \geq 0\\
\left(t - \frac{7}{4}\right)^2 - \frac{89}{16} & \leq 0\\
\left(t - \frac{7}{4}\right)^2 & \leq \frac{89}{16}\\
\left|t - \frac{7}{4}\right| & \leq \frac{\sqrt{89}}{4}
\end{align*}
is satisfied if 
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\sqrt{89}}{4} & < t - \frac{7}{4} < \frac{\sqrt{89}}{4}\\
\frac{7 - \sqrt{89}}{4} & < t < \frac{7 + \sqrt{89}}{4}
\end{align*}
Since 
$$\frac{7 - \sqrt{89}}{4} \approx −0.608495283$$
and 
$$\frac{7 + \sqrt{89}}{4} \approx 4.108495283$$
we may conclude that $v(t) > 0$ in the interval $[0, 2.5]$, so $v(t) = |v(t)|$ in this interval.

Since $v(t) = |v(t)|$, the distance traveled in time $t$ is 
\begin{align*}
d(T) & = \int_{0}^{T} |v(t)|~dt\\
     & = \int_{0}^{T} v(t)~dt\\
     & = -\frac{0.2T^3}{3} + \frac{0.7T^2}{2} + 0.5T\\
     & = -\frac{T^3}{15} + \frac{7T^2}{20} + \frac{T}{2}
\end{align*}
based on our calculations above.

Hence,
\begin{align*}
d(1) & = -\frac{1^3}{15} + \frac{7(1^2)}{20} + \frac{1}{2}\\
     & = -\frac{1}{15} + \frac{7}{20} + \frac{1}{2}\\
     & = -\frac{4}{60} + \frac{21}{60} + \frac{30}{60}\\
     & = \frac{47}{60}\\
\end{align*}

Another approach is 
\begin{align*}
d(1) & = \int_{0}^{1} v(t)~dt\\
     & = \int_{0}^{1} (-0.2t^2 + 0.7t + 0.5)~dt\\
     & = \int_{0}^{1} \left(-\frac{1}{5}t^2 + \frac{7}{10}t + \frac{1}{2}\right)~dt\\
     & = \left(-\frac{1}{15}t^3 + \frac{7}{20}t^2 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1\right)\bigg|_{0}^{1}\\
     & = -\frac{1}{15} \cdot 1^3 + \frac{7}{20} \cdot 1^2 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 - \left(-\frac{1}{15} \cdot 0^3 + \frac{7}{20} \cdot 0^2 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0\right)\\
     & = -\frac{1}{15} + \frac{7}{20} + \frac{1}{2} - (-0 + 0 + 0)\\
     & = \frac{47}{60}
\end{align*}

Try working out $d(2)$.

> Using the formula $s(T) = -\dfrac{1}{15}T^3 + \dfrac{7}{20}T^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}T$, you should obtain \begin{align*} d(2) & = -\frac{2^3}{15} + \frac{7 \cdot 2^2}{20} + \frac{1 \cdot 2}{2}\\ & = -\frac{8}{15} + \frac{28}{20} + 1\\ & = -\frac{8}{15} + \frac{7}{5} + 1\\ & = -\frac{8}{15} + \frac{21}{15} + \frac{15}{15}\\ & = \frac{28}{15}\end{align*}

Comment: Have you completed the question for me?

Comment: I answered the first question.  As for finding the distance, I showed that $|v(t)| = v(t)$, so $d(T) = S(T)$.  Since $s(0) = 0$, you merely need to evaluate $s(1)$ in the second part and $s(2)$ in the third part.

Comment: I will have a go at these now, and post my answer

Comment: I have gone through your workings out, and watched some you tube videos. I understand to an extend. but struggling to complete distance over 1 and 2 minutes.

Comment: I have added two different ways of calculating $d(1)$ and provided a hidden answer for $d(2)$ for you to check after you have attempted that calculation.  Just hover over the shadow box.

Comment: So far i have this: $$d(2) = - \frac{2^3}{15} + {7(2^2)}{20} + \frac{1}{2}$$ $$= \frac{8}{15} + {28}{20} + {1}{2}$$. Is this correct? If so what do i do next? I have tried a few different things, but i think going wrong at this point

Comment: You transcribed the formula $$d(T) = -\frac{T^3}{15} + \frac{7T^2}{20} + \frac{T}{2}$$ incorrectly.  If you fix that, you should get the answer I obtained in the shadow box.  You will have to put the three terms over a common denominator in order to add them.